# Command pattern, need to create new commands before executing

Tags: command-pattern

I use command pattern in one my application, and I have following problem:
Some commands need another commands to be created before they are executed. 
The need to create new commands depends on state of application, so I can not resolve whether to create new commands when adding commands to queue, but I need to resolve it just before they are executed.
Specifically, I make commands to control one strategy game. I have command to upgrade building. And it takes resources. 
When the resources price is higher than my storages capacity, the program should resolve it and insert commands for upgrading resource storages before the actual upgrade of building. This is why I can not resolve the need to upgrade storages when adding this command to queue, because the command could be executed after many days and levels of storages will change over time.
The only option that came to my mind is to insert new commands before command which needs more resources than I can have in my storages, and restart the executing of commands queue from the beginning, but it is really ugly solution. 
Is there some design pattern to resolve command dependencies only when command is first in queue to be executed and to insert those depencies before this command to be executed?
I need to add the commands to upgrade storages to queue, so they could be persisted for later executing when I currently have no resources to upgrade storages.
My QueueConsumer, where the queue procesing logic is, looks like this:

```
public function processQueue()
{
    $failedCommands = [];
    $success = false;
    $queue = $this->queueManager->getQueue();
    foreach ($queue as $key => $command) {
        foreach ($this->processors as $processor) {
            if ($processor->canProcessCommand($command)) {
                $success = $processor->processCommand($command);
                //in the processCommandMethod I am able to resolve whether I need new commands (need to upgrade storages) or not
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($success) {
            $this->queueManager->removeFromQueue($command->getUuid());
        } else {
            $failedCommands[] = $command;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count($failedCommands) > 0) {
    //determine when the failed commands could be processed succesfully (enough resources and so on).
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an IoC container? It would resolve all dependecies for you.

Comment: I propably did not express myself clearly. I use Dependency Injection container, I do not have problem with dependencies in terms of service classes, but I need to resolve dependencies in term of some command to be inserted to queue (because I need to persist the newly added command to be processed later) before currently processed command and executed before it.

Comment: May be you could move your logic to a state machine. You could considere the comands as the alphabet of the SM

Comment: In the trasitions you actually do the logic.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds useful. But I also need to add the commands to the queue array during the foreach traversing, but I will propably do that just by using some wrapper object.
Can I add +1 to the comment with state machine?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a word here. How can I add +1 to the comment? I see only possibility to add +1 to the answer, not the comment.